# Multiple s1._domainkey DNS entries

Tags: domain-name-system, email

I need to setup multiple values for s1._domainkey and s2._domainkey CNAME domain entries for different vendors. How can i append multiple values for s1 and s2 domain keys?

Answer (score 6):

No you cannot, the purpose of the sector is to have multiple keys under multiple names, does the vendor allow you to pick your own sectors??  Also it is illegal to have multiple CNAMEs

For example, each of my 3 outbound servers signed dkim with their own keys.

vegas._domainkey.jacobdevans.com
lux._domainkey.jacobdevans.com
jersey._domainkey.jacobdevans.com

The reason they use to sectors is for key rotation.

If it were possible to round robin the record, your email (if DNS round robin was actually evenly load balanced) would fail signing verification 50% of the time.

Comment: Thanks.  This was helpful for me.  I realised I could get SendGrid to nominate a custom 3 character key since I'd already created CNAMEs for another service.

Comment: there's a handy up arrow you can use to signify the answer was helpful